# Grouping based on conditions and putting them into a single row in XSLT Transformation

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am facing a problem in transformation of XML. I need to transform an output in csv file as with ',' seperated.

XML:

```
<Root>
<Employees>
<Employee>
<Co_Code>DEEP1</Co_Code>
<ID>12345</ID>
</Employee>
<Type Descriptor="Phone"></Type>
<amount1>8</amount1>
</Employees>
<Employees>
<Employee>
<Co_Code>DEEP1</Co_Code>
<ID>12345</ID>
</Employee>
<Type Descriptor="Phone"></Type>
<amount>6</amount>
</Employees>
<Employees>
<Employee>
<Co_Code>DEEP1</Co_Code>
<ID>12345</ID>
</Employee>
<Type Descriptor="Food"></Type>
<amount>8</amount>
</Employees>
<Employees>
<Employee>
<Co_Code>DEEP1</Co_Code>
<ID>12345</ID>
</Employee>
<Type Descriptor="Travel"></Type>
<amount>8</amount>
</Employees>
<Employees>
<Employee>
<Co_Code>DEEP1</Co_Code>
<ID>12345</ID>
</Employee>
<Type Descriptor="Other"></Type>
<amount>800</amount>
</Employees>
<Employees>
<Employee>
<Co_Code>DEEP1</Co_Code>
<ID>12346</ID>
</Employee>
<Type Descriptor="Phone"></Type>
<amount>8</amount>
</Employees>
<Employees>
<Employee>
<Co_Code>DEEP1</Co_Code>
<ID>12346</ID>
</Employee>
<Type Descriptor="Phone"></Type>
<amount>8</amount>
</Employees>
<Employees>
<Employee>
<Co_Code>DEEP1</Co_Code>
<ID>12346</ID>
</Employee>
<Type Descriptor="Other"></Type>
<amount>8</amount>
</Employees>
<Employees>
<Employee>
<Co_Code>DEEP1</Co_Code>
<ID>12346</ID>
</Employee>
<Type Descriptor="Food"></Type>
<amount>8</amount>
</Employees>
</Root>
```

Currently using XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="sep" select="', '"/>

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:value-of select="'Co Code', 'ID', 'type', 'amount'" separator="{$sep}"/>
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="Employees" group-adjacent="Type/@Descriptor">
    <xsl:if test="position() gt 1"><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="Employee/Co_Code, Employee/ID, current-grouping-key(), sum(current-group()/amount)"
      separator="{$sep}"/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently generating the Output in below format:

```
Co Code, ID, type, amount
DEEP1, 12345, Phone, 6
DEEP1, 12345, Food, 8
DEEP1, 12345, Travel, 8
DEEP1, 12345, Other, 800
DEEP1, 12346, Phone, 16
DEEP1, 12346, Other, 8
DEEP1, 12346, Food, 8
```

But i need to arrange the few row into column . 
I am trying to get the output in below format.
Employee Sum of Phone and Food should be written in one seperate column and For other type it should create a seperate line with Phone and Food column as blank.

```
Co Code, ID,  Phone , Food, type,  amount
DEEP1, 12345,   6   ,  8  ,       ,
DEEP1, 12345,       ,     , Travel, 8
DEEP1, 12345,               Other, 800
DEEP1, 12346,  16   ,  8  ,       ,
DEEP1, 12346,       ,     , Other, 8
```

Please give me some idea to achieve this.

Thanks to [Martin Honnen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen) for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to start off by grouping by the Employee's ID

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Employees"  
                    group-by="Employee/ID">
```

You then have a specific line for outputting the "Food" and "Phone" values

```
<xsl:value-of select="Employee/Co_Code, 
                      current-grouping-key(), 
                      sum(current-group()[Type/@Descriptor = 'Phone']/amount), 
                      sum(current-group()[Type/@Descriptor = 'Food']/amount), 
                      '', 
                      ''"  separator="{$sep}"/>
```

And within the current group, you can then group the non "Food" and "Phone" entries by their descriptor (This would only be necessary if the descriptors can be repeated)

```
 <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[not(Type/@Descriptor = ('Phone', 'Food'))]" 
                     group-by="Type/@Descriptor">
```

Then it is a straight-forward case of outputting a line for this too.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="sep" select="', '"/>

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="Root">
    <xsl:value-of select="'Co Code', 'ID', 'type', 'amount'" separator="{$sep}"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Employees" group-by="Employee/ID">
        <xsl:value-of select="Employee/Co_Code, current-grouping-key(), sum(current-group()[Type/@Descriptor = 'Phone']/amount), sum(current-group()[Type/@Descriptor = 'Food']/amount), '', ''"  separator="{$sep}"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()[not(Type/@Descriptor = ('Phone', 'Food'))]" group-by="Type/@Descriptor">
            <xsl:value-of select="Employee/Co_Code, '', '', sum(current-group()/amount), current-group()/Type/@Descriptor"  separator="{$sep}"/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```